# How to refresh linked tables if Access disconnects from MySQL database server?

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, odbc

So, I need a way to refresh the linked tables in my Access Database so that if the Internet disconnects for some reason the ODBC won't have an error when a query is sent and simply refreshes to see if the query can be sent again. However, the Access database doesn't reconnect for some reason when the Internet comes back up. Is there a way, in VBA, to refresh the linked tables if this does happen?

Answer (score 1):

Would the `.RefreshLink` method do what you want?

There's an example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198349.aspx

Another solution would be to reconnect to the remote database calling this function.

```
Function ConnectODBC(ByVal strDsn As String, ByVal strDatabase As String, ByVal strUserName As String, ByVal strPassword As String)

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strConnection As String

    strConnection = "ODBC;DSN=" & strDsn & ";" & _
                    "DATABASE=" & strDatabase & ";" & _
                    "UID=" & strUserName & ";" & _
                    "PWD=" & strPassword

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")

    With qdf
        .Connect = strConnection
        .SQL = "SELECT 1;"
    End With

    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot, dbSQLPassThrough)
    ConnectODBC = True

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: I tried that, but then I get the error "ODBC Failed Call."

Comment: there's already an answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15665509/4510359. 
It looks like this:
`Dim db as Database
Set db = Currentdb()
db.TablesDefs(1).RefreshLink`
Is it what you typed?

Comment: I did: CurrentDb().TableDefs(1).RefreshLink and I got the error "Run-time error '3146'

ODBC -- call failed."

Comment: I edited my answer with another solution I use on one of my applications.

Comment: Scratch that, thank you for the help. I'll try it out.

Comment: I tried using that function and it still has the same problem. I put my data source name, which was "database", and I put the name of the database I want to connect to. I then put the user and pass of that database. I click a button in Access that uses that function and then I click a button to submit a query. It still has the ODBC error.

Comment: that's the data source name or the name of your ODBC connection. If you don't remember it, you can find it in the Linked Table Manager after the table name. ex: `my_linked_table(DSN:foo;DATABASE:bar)`

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but when I close the form and try to reopen it again, I get the error "ODBC -- Call Failed - MySQL as gone away."

Comment: this could be caused by MySQL settings like timeout. Does your ODBC connection works when you first open your Access database?

Comment: How often do you lose your connection? You may have problems with your ODBC or MySQL settings. Try to increase the timeout in MySQL.

Comment: I don't lose connection much, but I want the application to have a fail-safe so that if it does disconnect it can reconnect with no problem. Also, how would I increase the timeout in myphpadmin?